# Limit performance for a known number of records

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume I have a simple select * from table; query where I know beforehand how many entries exist. Let's say 100.

Are there any performance differences between these three calls?
1) select * from table;
2) select * from table limit 100;
3) select * from table limit 1000;

Each of those calls will return exactly 100 rows. Do the different limit values, or no limit value, affect how fast the call will be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the performance is easily testable.

Comment: You'd have to try each query and measure the results to be sure.  But I'm guessing that there is not a significant performance difference if the limit equals or exceeds the actual number of records.

Comment: I think that is important to set limit. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html)

Comment: I doubt there would be much if any difference.   If anything adding the LIMIT statement would be slightly slower because it has to confirm the number of rows returned is still below that limit.  But i strongly doubt it would even be close to noticeable.

Comment: You would not see a valuable difference between this queries. This is not the `limit` that affects your performance but `offset`. I do agree with @JustinNiessner and I think you spent more time writing this question  than you could spend writing a simple PHP script to test it you by yourself.

Comment: Either way is a full table scan.  Because there is no real where clause, the limit will have no effect except in the case that there are more than the limit clause.  In which case it will STILL do a full table scan.  It will just return the number of rows from 0 to limit-1 (using index 0).

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` allows the engine to deliver arbitrary rows.  But it will be faster for a lower `LIMIT` -- the time is essentially proportional to the number of rows delivered.

`ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` *may* have to sort the entire table before delivering some subset of rows.  So, it is likely to be slower than without the `ORDER BY`, perhaps a lot slower.

With an `ORDER BY`, the speed *may* depend on what index(es) you have and what is in the `WHERE` clause.

My point is -- There are so many things going on in a *realistic* query that a one-line answer to your question will provide virtually no usable information.

Answer (score -1):

It totally depends on the database you are using (even different mysql versions probably make a difference).

You will probably have a performance difference between specifying limit and not specifying limit (although very minor). Since the database might make a different execution plan.

But this is only initialy since most databases cache queries. (She make sure when you test this performance that you disable this)

Comment: "You will probably have a performance difference between specifying limit and not specifying limit. ". In what cases? OP has clearly mentioned the rows are within limit.

Comment: If only for sending 10 more characters to the db service which means bigger request payload. I agree this is on nano level and you shouldn't worry about this, but then the question is not very specific.